# Azure Search Suggestions relevancy

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've been using Azure Search for indexing products on an eCommerce site. It works for 'Product Matches' using the Search API. I was able to configure the Scoring Profile to get me the results I need from the Search API.

However, I would also like to use the 'Suggestions API' to show the most relevant results as the user types text in the search box. But the results being shown are not most relevant since there is no way to apply scoring functions to the suggestions API.

I would like to boost most relevant products to the top of the suggestions when using the Suggestions API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, scoring profiles are not supported in the Azure Search Suggestions API and there is no other built-in way to influence ranking for Suggestions. Please vote for this feature on [Azure Search User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) page to help us prioritize.